# What is the difference between the freezing level and 0 C isotherm in NOAA's GFS?

Tags: meteorology, models, weather-forecasting, gfs

I'm playing around with NOAA's GFS forecast data and I see that it contains both a "0 °C isotherm level" and a "Highest tropospheric freezing level".

Could someone tell me the difference between these two levels? I'd assume they are the same except in the case of an inversion.

Comment: One of the effects is the change of freezing point with pressure: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60170/freezing-point-of-water-with-respect-to-pressure

Comment: Unfortunately that's not relevant in this situation, the temperature difference in freezing point is very small on atmospheric scales.

Comment: If you read the physics.stackexchange, that is exactly what they say.

Comment: From browsing a few OPeNDAP servers that provide both the "highest tropospheric freezing level" and the "0C isotherm level", that's exactly what I see (that the difference between those levels is rather small).

Comment: I understand "0 °C isotherm level" as "Lowest tropospheric freezing level", so it is lowest versus highest. If temperature in the troposphere profile crosses  0 °C just once, their altitude is the same. But due various inversion layers, temperature can cross  0 °C multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Various processes affect the freezing point. Both CCN (cloud condensation nuclei) characteristics and drop size affect the freezing point.